# Department sites having multiple projects and different files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sub-site

I am at a company with several departments, and has different projects, here is an example...

Marketing Department has a Website Update Project, a Bugs Project, and an Email campaign project. These projects need to have their own document libraries, task lists and discussion boards.

What woould be the most efficient way of doing this? Would I have to manually create different subsites and apps for each project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your needs in terms of:

- Permissions
- Number of projects
- Number of documents per project
- Cross project/department integration
- ...

it's hard to give real good advise, but as a baseline my recommendations would be:

- Create Site Collection per department to handle permissions and possible split into multiple content databases
- Create Subsite per project if few/small
- Create Site Collection per project if many/large

The setup of project sites can be streamlined, by having a common Site Template from which they are created

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the advice, should have been more specific with the question. Teams will have no more than 10, and lots of projects. Just tried a subsite, and using the main site as a portal for each department. Thanks again! :)